# How to inject a font into js-only React application?

Tags: reactjs, fonts

I've got an app that is a part of a larger system. My app is distributed as a JS file, that is later embedded into HTML of another page. I don't have control over that HTML file.

I want to add a font from Google Fonts into my app. I have a [link](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open%20Sans&display=swap) to a stylesheet that imports and declares the fonts.

I've tried using `createGlobalStyle` from styled components or a CSS file referenced inside the file with main React component, to no avail — the font doesn't seem to be loaded, possibly because [`@import` declarations have to appear before other declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import), and my CSS is inlined into a random place in the document.

How do I insert them as before any other CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to add `<link rel="stylesheet" src="..." />` into *the head* using [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).

```
<Helmet>
  <link
   href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap"
   rel="stylesheet"
  />
</Helmet>
```